# Track email send-out using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, email-tracking, survey

We want to setup a survey, which should be sent the day after the send-out have happened. We are trying to achieve this by using Automation studio and looking through the send and job data view. However, when trying to look for the send-outs the day before I am also getting the data of other send-outs that have been send many days prior. Does any one have a great solution to achieve this?

This is query I am working with so far:

```sql
SELECT  Count(s.EventDate)
FROM _Job j
JOIN _sent s
ON j.JobID = S.JobID
WHERE j.EMailName LIKE 'EMAIL_NAME'
AND s.EventDate BETWEEN Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE) AND
                               Cast(
                               Getdate() AS DATE)
GROUP BY  s.EventDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a send count for a particular email for yesterday:

```sql
SELECT 
Count(*) sendCount
FROM _Job j
INNER JOIN _sent s ON S.JobID = j.JobID 
WHERE j.EMailName LIKE '%YOUREMAILNAMEPATTERNHERE%'
AND s.EventDate >= convert(date, getDate()-1) 
and s.EventDate < convert(date, getDate()) 
GROUP BY convert(date, s.EventDate)
```

Translation:

Give me a count of all sends to emails that contain `YOUREMAILNAMEPATTERN` that occurred up to and after midnight yesterday and before midnight today.